# Tableau automatic resizing is throwing the contents of the dashboard all over the place

Tags: tableau-api, fullscreen, image-resizing, window-resize

I wanted to know how the below functionalities can be achieved on tableau:
1. Resize the dashboard on the tableau server based on the screen size and
2. Maintain the % area occupied by each visual (worksheets on the dashboard) on the tableau server to be constant.
Ex, a visual should occupy 30% of the total width and 40% of the total height of the dashboard such that, regardless of the screen size, if this kind of height and width % are defined for every dashboard then the visuals will all be proportional to the screen size.

Situation:
I've built a dashboard with a lot of visuals (3 x 3 matrix of visuals) and each of different sizes. When I fix the size of the dashboard, it all looks good but when published on the server there's an obvious issue of scroll appearing on the web page depending on the screen size of the desktop it is being opened in.
I know tableau has an automatic resizing feature. But the issue is - I have almost 9 images on my dashboard and if I allow tableau to resize based on the screen, the height and width are out of control and some of the alignments are out of place as well.

Current settings:
I've made sure the worksheets on the dashboards are all within containers and I also know that i should not be fixing the height or width given we want the automatic resizing to work based on screen size.

Comment: Are you only publishing the dashboards, or both dashboards and the accompanying sheets? Uploading sheets as part of a workbook throws automatic resizing out of whack for some reason.